# Select number of x-files in directory in a loop

Tags: python

I have a directory that consists of multiple images taken of multiple persons. Each person has 8 pictures. I want to know how I can select all the pictures of a single person in a loop. So each time 8 pictures are selected. I came up with the following:

```
import glob
import os, os.path

path = 'C:/Users/HJA/Desktop/Teeth/Photos'
files = glob.glob('C:/Users/HJA/Desktop/Teeth/Photos/*.jpeg')
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)

for x in range(8):
   DoSomething
```

Can anyone help me to create batches of each person?

Comment: is there something in the filename that differentiates one person's image from another? If so, please include that in the question :)

Comment: No, it's all the same. I thought about creating something like batch_1 = [files[0], files[1], ...m files[8]] etc. But the number of photos vary. But they are always in a x-fold of 8 and by sorting on time I can make sure that they are bundles together

Comment: does this mean the first 8 photos, sorted by timestamp, are of one person. the next 8 photos are of a second person, so on?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

If all the files are sorted then first 8 files belong to one person and next 8 belong to second person and so on. SO creating a new dir for each person with name being the timestamp or you can change it to a counter like 1,2,3 etc.

```
import os, datetime
import shutil
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
for x in range(0,len(files),8):
    mydir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))#os.getcwd() -> target dir
    os.makedirs(mydir)
    for file_ptr in range(x,x+8):
        shutil.copy(files[file_ptr],os.path.join(os.getcwd(),mydir)
```

Could not test it but logically speaking it should work